# IBM Worklight Studio 6.1 - Installation fails with Rational Developer for System Z 9.0.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-rad, ibm-rational

I've tried this installation with WL Studio 6.0 and 6.1, from the downloaded Consumer Edition and also the Enterprise Edition, and from the [Worklight update site](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/).  I get the following error message:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: IBM Worklight Studio
>   6.1.0.01-20140311-2356 (com.ibm.imp.tools.feature.feature.group 6.1.0.01-20140311-2356)   Missing requirement: Ui 6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 (com.ibm.imp.worklight.ui 6.1.0.00-20131126-0630) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.discovery 1.0.0' but it could not be
>   found...

This is on a brand new Win7 machine.
I am told these levels can share a shell.

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know the version of your Eclipse the Rational developer used? In the log, it says  "requires  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.discovery 1.0.0' but it could not be found", which means the problem maybe in Eclipse.

Worklight 6.1 requires one of the following Eclipse

- Eclipse Juno v4.2.2 (SR2)
- Eclipse Kepler v4.3.1 (SR1)
- Eclipse Classic v4.2.2
- Eclipse Classic v4.3.1

Comment: Yes, apparently RDz 9.0.1 is still based on Eclipse 4.2.1, not 4.2.2.  That is surprising since apparently RDz 9.0 and Worklight 6.0, and RDz 9.0.1 and Worklight 6.1 (same Eclipse base as the other combination) are supposed to share a shell just fine.  Yet on a completely fresh Win 7 install I had the error above.  Inexplicable, but true.  I've been using Eclipse since 2001 so I am well versed in these intricacies.  Here's how

Comment: Yes, it seems RDz 9.0.1 is still based on Eclipse 4.2.1, not 4.2.2. Surprising since apparently RDz 9.0/9.0.1 and Worklight 6.0/6.1 are supposed to share a shell just fine. Yet on a completely fresh Win7 install I had that error. I've been using Eclipse since 2001 so I am versed in these intricacies. Here's how I solved it:

I installed RDz 9.0.1. Then I updated from Eclipse Juno repository - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno as many (base-like) packages as I thought made sense. I guess one was the key. Then I installed WL 6.1 and all worked! Nice combination in the same shell!